# How to change button text color programmatically on press?

Tags: java, android

I create button like this:

```
Button button = new Button(this); 
button.setText("2012");
button.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
button.setOnClickListener(mCorkyListener);
layout.addView(dateButton);
```

On click listiner i have this method. Here i want to change button text color. Bu View don't have this method

```
    private OnClickListener mCorkyListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
          // do something when the button is clicked
            //v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
//so how to change pressed button text color ?
//v.setTextColor(colors);
        }
    };
```

There wouldn't be just one button. There would be many of those and i need to chnage text color when button pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private OnClickListener mCorkyListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {          
     Button button = (Button)v;
     button.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked about changing text color, and everyone else has pretty well covered that, but you could also change the button color itself (which I find much more visible than a text color change :p)...

```
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
```

To set it to green (assuming you start with a standard gray button):

```
aButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Button aButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.abutton);
        aButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFF00FF00, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks your this code, but my idea is to do click able text and not to show button, for that reason my button background is transparent.

Comment: I would give +1 for sharing. Though answer is not what the user asked for :)

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

This will change the textcolor of the button.Do u want to give a press effet to button when click on it?

Comment: My press effect would be changed text color

Comment: checkout this link adding selector as your button background will help you to do so.But before that give two resources to add to selelctor.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do this is not programmatically (using [selector](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/)), but if you want to do it programmatically you can cast it to `Button` and then change the color.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(v.getId());
    b.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)l
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested to use the View of `onClick(View v)` then just cast it to Button

```
     public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v instanceof Button){
              ((Button)v).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
           }
     }
```